# (Python) PyInstaller unicode error

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a webscraper that I'm working on to see if it will run properly on other systems. I'm using pyinstaller 3.0. Followed install instructions, installed prerequisites, no errors.

When I try to compile it using:

```
pyinstaller wowscrape.py
```

I get this unicode error:

```
...
File "C:\Users\brian_000\Documents\GitHubVisualStudio\wowscrape\wowscrape\wowscrape\wowscrape.py" line 1
  \ufeffimport os
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

The only stuff I could find on unicode and pyinstaller had to do with installing it on linux.

I dug through the build folder and noticed that inside the "base_library" rar that there are handlers for unicode, so I'm not sure what it's getting hung up on.

I'm using Python 3.4, in this project I have:

```
os
sys
urllib
bs4
pyqt5
loginwindow << is an import from qt designer converted to python
mainwindow << is an import from qt designer converted to python
```

If there isn't a way to make this work with pyinstaller, are there any other options? I haven't seen much support for packing Python 3 into exe's with cross system support. Since it's a scraper based around WoW, I would like to have this produce applications for Win/Mac/Nix.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the main script I'm trying to build, if it will help.
I know, it's messy and long. It's still being prototyped.
[link to code](http://pastebin.com/Wp4YpVyx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your file in an editor encoded as UTF-8 **without** byte order mark (BOM) and try again. A decent editor should have a menu entry such as `File --> Save with encoding`.

Comment: `Notepad++` for example can be used

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realize that was an issue. I was using notepad++ for a while but then decided to move to VS 2015. moved it all back into notepad++, saved over the files, and it works. Thanks :)